# node.tpl render field from referenced entity

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I have a node.tpl.php file where I need to output a field from an entity referenced via the entity module (a reference field). I have tried using:

```
print render($content['field_parent']['#items'][0]['entity']->field_main_image);
```

but nothing appears! I also tried this way:

```
$parent = node_load($node->field_parent['und'][0]['target_id']);
print render($parent->field_main_image);
```

I just would like to render() a related field just as I do with $content fields.

Any hints ?
Thank you

Comment: How are you getting your $node object?

Comment: it comes as a default variable from drupal core

Comment: I mean would help to show it in your code. Have you tried a var dump of $node to see if you are getting any data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_display to do that with entity reference and field collection field.

Answer (score 0):

You can't render the member variable of a node directly. In a frist step you have to bring it in a renderable from (array):

```
//returns the field in the correct language
$field_parent = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_parent');

//retruns an array which you can render
$render_array = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_parent', $field_parent [0]);

print render ($render_array);
```

Here's the differents between the two structures of these arrays. The array in the member variable of $node looks like:

```
array(1) {
  ["und"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(15) "Your value"
      ["format"]=>
      NULL
      ["safe_value"]=>
      string(15) "Your value"
    }
  }
}
```

A renderable array (for a textfield) looks like that:

```
array(2) {
  ["#markup"]=>
  string(18) "Your value"
  ["#access"]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$parent = node_load($node->field_parent['und'][0]['target_id']);
print render($parent->field_main_image);
```

should work as

```
$parent = node_load($node->field_parent['und'][0]['target_id']);
print drupal_render(field_view_field('node', $parent, 'field_main_image', 'displayname'));
```